# Woocommerce subscription first checkout as "Charge" and renewal as "Authorize"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscription, authorize.net, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using Woocommerce subscription with Authorize.net payment plugin. Payment plugin offers two method to accept payment either "Charge" or "Authorize". By default settings on checkout page is "Charge" and that is correct. I need to use "Authorize" method on renewal orders.

I have tried this hook from authorize.net plugin but this did not work -

```
add_filter( 'wc_authorize_net_cim_credit_card_perform_credit_card_charge', 'switch_charge_to_authorize', 10, 2 ); 
function switch_charge_to_authorize($perform, $order){
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    if(wcs_order_contains_renewal( $order )){
        error_log('renewal processed for order '.$order->get_id());
        $param = false;
    } 
    return $param;
}
```

Any suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks